# C# MySql Connector/Net issues

Tags: c#, mysql, connector-net, idbconnection

Currently running Mono. I loaded MySQL and installed connector/net in my gac folder located in /usr/lib/mono/gac. The problem is that everytime I try to run it using a simple connection test, I get the following error:

```
** (/home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe:10278): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   MySql.Data    (assemblyref_index=1)
     Version:    6.4.4.0
     Public Key: c5687fc88969c44d
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/).


** (/home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe:10278): WARNING **: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.

** (/home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe:10278): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe, type MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

** (/home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe:10278): WARNING **: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.

** (/home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe:10278): WARNING **: Missing method .ctor in assembly /home/holland/Code/csharp/test/Test/bin/Debug/Test.exe, type MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at Test.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It *should* be an assembly file if I recall correctly

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Test
{
    public class Database
    {
        public Database()
        {

        }

        public static IDbConnection MainConnect()
        {
            string connectionInfo = 
            "Server=localhost;"+
            "Database=ecom_main;"+
            "User ID=root;"+
            "Password=xxxxxxx"+
            "Pooling=false;";

            return new MySqlConnection(connectionInfo);
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            IDbConnection dbMain = Database.MainConnect();

            Console.WriteLine(dbMain);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check that that's the same folder as the MONO_PATH variable?

Comment: Where is the MONO_PATH variable?

Comment: How did you install the assembly? Did you use gacutil?

Comment: MONO_PATH is an environment variable, and as Jon says did you use gacutil to register it with the GAC, placing it in the folder doesn't always work.

Comment: Update: I did an export MONO_PATH on the directory, and I wasn't able to get anything unfortunately.

Comment: I did use gacutil -i /path/to/dll to install it. Then I loaded it as an assembly in the 'edit references' module of MonoDevelop.

Comment: So, did I install it correctly or was there something wrong which I forgot to do?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it following this steps:

1. Make a copy case sesitive of the dll:

```
#cp mysql.data.dll MySql.Data.dll
```

1. Install the connector

   ```
   #gacutil -i -package 2.0 MySql.Data.dll
   ```

   This installs in the GAC and also adds a symlink in /usr/lib/mono/2.0
2. If the assembly does not appear in monodevelop, then you can add a reference to the dll in the project to /usr/lib/mono/2.0

+info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-installation-unix.html

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Was enough to just make it case sensative (Running Ubuntu). Thanks.

Comment: Same for me. Renaming `mysql.data.dll` to `MySql.Data.dll` makes mono run without any problems.

Comment: Making it case sensitive helped me as well, ridiculous :p